# html img has an extra space on content-box

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[you can watch my problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA2ji.png)

I used bootstrap and when i put images it automatically make extra space on content-box like an image that i uploaded.
Any properties don't work for me.

This only happens when the max-width is 992px

```
 <section class="page-section mb-0" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- About Section Heading-->
    <h2 class="page-section-heading text-center">
      About
    </h2>
    <!-- Divider-->
    <div class="divider-custom divider-light">
      <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- About Section Content-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto">
        <img class="demo" src="assets/img/demo.jpg" alt="image" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 mr-auto">
        <p class="lead">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia neque assumenda ipsam nihil, molestias magnam, recusandae quos quis inventore quisquam velit asperiores, vitae? Reprehenderit soluta, eos quod consequuntur itaque. Nam.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a code example, including what you've already tried?

Comment: You need to add width 100% css to your img tag style="width:100%" OR class  class="img-fluid"

Comment: You may need to give display:block; to the image and maybe oberflow:hidden; to the parent div

Answer (score -1):

Can't offer a proper answer without an example code given, but looks like this may solve the issue:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```